# I don't know how to find Views by Id

Tags: android

Helo, 
I have a problem with finding views by Id. I don't know what is the difference between view.getId() and finViewbyId methods and when to use each of them?

Comment: Look at the documentation before posting a question

Answer (score 1):

> view.getId

Returns the "android:id" value

> findViewbyId

Allows you to get the object and use it

Answer (score 0):

```
view.getId()
```

Gives you an int id, assigned to view in xml layout. And

```
findViewbyId()
```

gives you a view object by id that you need to write in arguments.